# Test installing a package into a developer account

Tags: developer-edition

I have built an integration between my company's product and salesforce which required custom objects. I packaged this all up into a package and wanted to test the installation of this so I could document it with screenshots.

The only other account I have is a developer account but when I install it, salesforce gives me errors around lead's. I assume this is the limits of a developer account? or am i missing something. Installing it to another product account has presented the same errors

```
This app can't be installed.
There are problems that prevent this package from being installed.
Leads Missing Organization Feature: Lead.RecordType
Leads Missing Organization Feature: Lead.Sharing
Leads Missing Organization Feature: Lead.FieldHistoryTracking
```

Comment: Please create a Lead Record Type, and some custom sharing rule. Enable field history tracking for lead. This might solve your problem

Comment: i think the developer account should have all this set up with test data

Answer (score 1):

You have baked those pre-requisite requirements into your package. If they are genuinely required, then that is fine and your should be able to turn them on in the developer account org and install and test.

But if your package functionality does not require these features then it would be best to create a package that will work either with or without those features present. That greatly expands the orgs your package can be installed in. That will involve tracking down where your code explicitly references e.g. history or sharing objects at compile time and removing that code or replacing it with e.g. dynamic rather than static SOQL.

Comment: You are correct. i have built a child object that add's data to the parent lead object, therefore I ticked all the lead boxes when i went to created the version of the app thinking they where required. If i don't specify this will my app install ok? Even though the package works with leads. It fails even when i add the package to my salesforce even though i use leads all the time!?

Comment: @ChrisMccabe Not quite sure what you were ticking but record types, sharing and field history tracking are optional so best if your product works with or without them. If manipulating Leads is central to your package then that dependency is OK.

Comment: Yes they are central to my product- i add data based on what the lead read on a website. I tried to install the app with both my normal sales account and my developer account and still got presented with these errors- even with leads being part of my normal usage??